# jquery animate and removeClass with addClass

Tags: jquery

When I "**removeClass('below')**", it removes the css class, but when I click on the object again it performs the same action.

I am trying to take away the ability for the click function to work by removing the css code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.below').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('below');
    $('#welcome').removeClass('fadeInLeft, bounceOutLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft');
    $('#welcome_search').delay('500').animate({"top": "-=140px"},"slow");
});
```

My html looks similar to this:

```
<div id="welcome_item" class="below">
    stuff
</div>
```

Please help with this, thank you.

What if I want to rebind the click after I change out the class?

```
$('.below').click(function() {
    $(this).unbind('click').removeClass('below').addClass('above');
    $('#welcome').removeClass('fadeInLeft bounceOutLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft');
    $('#welcome_search').delay('500').animate({"top": "-=140px"},"slow");
});

$('.above').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('above').addClass('below');
    $('#welcome_search').animate({"top": "+=140px"},"slow");
    $('#welcome').removeClass('fadeInLeft bounceOutLeft fadeOutLeft').delay('500').addClass('fadeInLeft');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time that jQuery code is run, the `click` event is already bound to the element with class `.below`, and everytime you click on the element, jQuery doesn't actually check the class of the element anymore, so removing class won't help you with this.

You can use `unbind` instead

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
$('.below').click(function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $('#welcome').removeClass('fadeInLeft, bounceOutLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft');
    $('#welcome_search').delay('500').animate({"top": "-=140px"},"slow");
});
```

Comment: That seems to work.  But what if I addClass('above') ?  And do a seperate click function for that?  how do I make it clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.off()`](http://jqapi.com/#p=off)

Removing the class is not enough, the event has been attached to the node, so you should remove the event attached to it too.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/8jt2A/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use

```
$('.below').live("click",function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unbind the event when you remove the class.

```
$('#foo').unbind('click');
```

So your js code should look like this.

```
$('.below').click(function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).removeClass('below');
    $('#welcome').removeClass('fadeInLeft, bounceOutLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft');
    $('#welcome_search').delay('500').animate({"top": "-=140px"},"slow");
});
```